# Ruby C extension can't be 'require'd

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

I have a ruby extension that I'm building as a gem. It has this directory structure

```
|-ext
  \-cowboy
    \- extconf.rb
    |- cowboy.c
|-lib
  \- cowboy.rb
  |- cowboy
    \- version.rb
|- test
  \- test_cowboy.rb
```

When I build it and install it, there are no errors, and 'require'ing the gem (e.g.
    require 'cowboy') works fine in irb.

However, when I run "ruby test/test_cowboy.rb" I get a load error from the require (it actually is complaining about "require 'cowboy/cowboy'" that lives in lib/cowboy.rb.

Does anyone know why???

Comment: What platform and Ruby version are you using? Does your `$LOAD_PATH` include the proper directories?

Comment: How do I check the load path? If I'm using bundler, should that take care of it? I'm using 'bundle exec ruby test/test_cowboy.rb'.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that:

1. in irb, when you `require 'cowboy'`, that tells rubygems to set up the load paths automatically to point to the currently installed gem dir.
2. when you run `test/test_cowboy.rb` it doesn't `require 'cowboy'`. This makes sense because during development, you don't want to load the installed version of the gem, which could be different from the code in your working dir.

I think you should create a `test/test_helper.rb` file that sets up the load path:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
```

You may need to add other dirs if the compiled shared object file (`.so` or `.bundle`) isn't placed in `lib`.

Then in each test file (e.g. `test/test_cowboy.rb`), require `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path('../test_helper.rb', __FILE__)
```

You'll need to adjust that relative path if you have subdirs. E.g. if you have a file `test/shoes/spur.rb`, you'd use:

```
require File.expand_path('../../test_helper.rb', __FILE__)
```

Comment: Looks right. However, I'm now running into the issue where my current test method 'gem build cowboy.gemspec && gem install cowboy-0.0.1.gem' doesn't seem to place the .bundle or .so anywhere. Should I be using a different mechanism to build during development?

Comment: You can use a rake task as described [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/#tutorial-rakefile). If you're still having trouble, please ask it as a separate question.